# Custom RadioButton Frame with text inside

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, controltemplate

I am trying to create a custom look for `RadioButton` different from the default one as shown in image below:

[image]

Any idea how can I do it?

Comment: use a ```CustomRenderer```

Comment: I know this is one of the directions for the solution, but I have not found any references to it on the web. Are you familiar with a suitable CustomRenderer?

Comment: a custom render means YOU need to write it.  Or just create a custom control using standard Forms UI elements.  Use some BoxViews with Labels and GestureRecognizers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from Xamarin forms `5.0.0.1539-pre2` version, `RadioButton` [does supports setting any content and using control templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/release-notes/5.0/5.0.0-pre2#getting-ready-for-xamarinforms-5) and thus less need for custom renderer, and if we combine this with [visual-state-manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/visual-state-manager) we will get a beautiful xaml:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="FrameRadioTemplate">
        <Frame Padding="0" BorderColor="#2B79E1" CornerRadius="15" VerticalOptions="Start"
               HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" HorizontalOptions="Start">

            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckedStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#2B79E1"/>
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>

                    <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#f3f2f1"/>
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

            <Grid Margin="4" WidthRequest="100">
                <ContentPresenter/>
            </Grid>
        </Frame>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center"  VerticalOptions="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <RadioButton ControlTemplate="{StaticResource FrameRadioTemplate}">
        <RadioButton.Content>
            <Label Text="RadioButton 1" TextColor="Black"/>
        </RadioButton.Content>
    </RadioButton>

    <RadioButton ControlTemplate="{StaticResource FrameRadioTemplate}">
        <RadioButton.Content>
            <Label Text="RadioButton 2" TextColor="Black"/>
        </RadioButton.Content>
    </RadioButton>
</StackLayout>
```

[image]

Inspired from [David Ortinau sample](https://gist.github.com/davidortinau/175b945ebab8448a86fe4b91d3f8b3eb)

---

**EDIT**

To make the `TextColor` white of the labels when respective `RadioButton` is checked you have several options:

1- Use a value converter with parameter bound to `IsCheked`.
2- Define style inline.
3- Use [Style.Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/triggers) inside the `ControlTemplate` which is shown below.

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="FrameRadioTemplate">
        <Frame Padding="5" CornerRadius="15" BorderColor="#2B79E1"
               HeightRequest="120" WidthRequest="120">

            <ContentPresenter>
                <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="Label">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center"/>
                        <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center"/>

                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger TargetType="Label"
                                         Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked,
                                                           Source={x:RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type RadioButton}}}"
                                         Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White"/>
                                <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ContentPresenter.Resources>
            </ContentPresenter>

            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckedStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#2B79E1"/>
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>

                    <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#f3f2f1"/>
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        </Frame>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="30"
                 VerticalOptions="Center">
        <RadioButton ControlTemplate="{StaticResource FrameRadioTemplate}" IsChecked="True">
            <RadioButton.Content>
                <Label Text="RadioButton 1" TextColor="Black"/>
            </RadioButton.Content>
        </RadioButton>

        <RadioButton ControlTemplate="{StaticResource FrameRadioTemplate}">
            <RadioButton.Content>
                <Label Text="RadioButton 2" TextColor="Black"/>
            </RadioButton.Content>
        </RadioButton>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

[image]

Comment: For font I don't know how to do it in `ControlTemplate` yet but I think you can create a value converter and send as a parameter IsChecked property.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you helped me a lot

Comment: Its impossible to click on the buttons, its now working for me.

Comment: @GuyP I am not sure what is the issue in your case, but at the time of my answer it was working properly could you provide more info that might help to understand the issue or post it as a new question ?

Comment: This issue was also raised at the provided snippet link that you provided. It might be a new bug for Maui. Buttons are not clickable anymore when setting this style.